# How to theme Profile 2 fields for anonymous?

Tags: 7, theming, users

I bring this question because I am not able to find the answer in anywhere, my apologies if it is a repeated one.

I have a Profile 2 type "curriculum_vitae", that I use to gather jobseekers CV.

I have all the Jobseeker's CVs  available for anonymous users which is working fine. My question how to theme the jobseeker's CV page "The page that will display to anonymous user once they click at the jobseeker profile".

I have a page named "profile2--curriculum_vitae.tpl.php" located at "\templates\profile2--curriculum_vitae.tpl.php".

I want to theme every single field of curriculum_vitae profile.

For example :

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<table class="table table-user-information">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><strong>Email:</strong></td>
<td>Here I want to print jobseeker's email in here, the filed machine name is "field_cv_email_address"</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template needs to be:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table table-user-information">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Email:</strong></td>
      <td><?php print render($content['field_cv_email_address']); ?></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, One last question. I want to use a condition to display user's personal information. I have a radio in p2 "field_cv_share_my_personal_info" with values public, private. 
Now if it was node I could have used 
"$field_items = 'field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_cv_share_my_personal_info');
<?php
if ($field_items[0]['value']=='Public') {
print render(email)
 }
else{
 print "Sorry not accessible to public";
}
?>
'"

Comment: You should be able to use similar code, the first argument to field_get_items should be 'profile' and the second argument will probably be $user or $profile

Answer (score 2):

You can create a View of *page* display of type `Profile types`

[image]

Then in this View add `curriculum_vitae` as *Relationships*, It causes the fields of  `curriculum_vitae` profile be added to the *Fields*.

Now create a *Contextual Filter* of any field you want (it might be name, ID, ...).

So you can easily theme this View to display the information of the selected user.  If the View name be *profile*, Then using `views-view-fields--profile--page.tpl.php` you can theme the output.

Answer (score 1):

Same Colin Shipton's answer and more for your question. Code in file profile2.tpl.php

```
<?php
$share = field_get_items('profile2', $profile2, 'field_cv_share_my_personal_info');
//dpm($share);
$email = $share[0]['value'] == 'YourValue'
  ? $content['field_cv_email_address']
  : t('Sorry not accessible to public"');
?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table table-user-information">
      <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Email:</strong></td>
        <td><?php print $email; ?></td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```